# Which domains need to be whitelisted for VSCode to load plugins?

Tags: visual-studio-code

We are behind a firewall with whitelisted domains, VS Code documentation puts the following list

```
update.code.visualstudio.com
code.visualstudio.com
go.microsoft.com
vscode.blob.core.windows.net
marketplace.visualstudio.com
*.gallery.vsassets.io
*.gallerycdn.vsassets.io
rink.hockeyapp.net
vscode.search.windows.net
raw.githubusercontent.com
vsmarketplacebadge.apphb.com
az764295.vo.msecnd.net
```

But that does seem a lot more than the plugin e.g. `hockeyapp.net`. Which ones would be needed just for downloading modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the devtools (<kbd>F1</kbd> -> `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools`) and go to the `Sources` tab there, you can reload the workspace (<kbd>F1</kbd> -> `Developer: Reload Window`). Then you can see which domains are requested.

[image]

You can also watch the console for errors.

```
*.gallery.vsassets.io
*.gallerycdn.vsassets.io
```

These should actually allow the downloading of extensions. Are you sure that the wildcards are working? I downloaded a couple of extensions, and they all fit into this domain space.